# RabbitMQ plugin configuration failure

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I have copied plugins to plugins folder in rabbitmq-server.

When I run command to enable stomp plugin like the following:

> $rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp
>
> Plugin configuration remains unchanged.
>
> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@pts00449-vm19... failed.
>   Error: {enabled_plugins_mismatch,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins",
>                                    "/does-not-exist"}

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: are you using the RabbitMQ server on windows platform?

Comment: @rezoan I am using rhel platform

Comment: I am unable to restart server.But I am able to run testcases related to stomp plugin. Which are all passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is plugins mismatch in your "enabled_plugins" directory.
Please check if you have enabled "rabbitmq_stomp" twice.

Try to disable the rabbitmq_stomp plugin and then you may restart the rabbitmq-server doing following steps:

```js
rabbitmq-plugins disable rabbitmq_stomp

rabbitmq-server start
```